# JMS listener using thread pool

Tags: spring, jms, threadpool, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I'm using a Spring project where I have an implementation of JMS Event listener to process messages from a queue.

To be precise, I'm using a SQS (AWS) queue.

All works fine.

My point is this:
I not configured anything about the concurrency but I would like to have more threads as listener to increase the performances (speed) about the messages processing from the queue.

I'm thinking about the possibility to configure a ThreadPool (TaskExecutor) and adding the annotation @Async on my methods about the message processing.

So, I will have a onMessage method into my listener where, after message validation I will call this async methods.

Is this a good practice? Will I have some issues using this approach?

I'm looking on the web for this and I see that I's possible to configure directly the concurrency value on the listener.

I'm very confusing there are a lot of possible ways to have this and I'm not able to understand the best approach.

Are these equivalent solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `@Async` - simply increase the concurrency of the listener container and it will be handled for you automatically by spring-jms.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide me an example of this? I don't see any concurrency setter on my Listener. The use of @Async is it a bad idea?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setConcurrentConsumers-int- Using `@Async` will cause lost messages in the event of a failure.

Comment: It's possible to use it if I'm using AWS SQS Implementation also? I don't have DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Comment: I am not sure what you mean; it looks like it does use it - see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-amazon-sqs-with-spring-boot-and-spring-jms/) and `factory.setConcurrency("3-10");`.